# R subset and tag data in data frame

Tags: r

Working through a course on R, and I've come across an issue with the course that I can't seem to solve.

I have a csv file which is read in as `delivery_data` then I'm to find all the rows that have a `pickup_zipcode` of 94107 that I then find all the rows that have either "Whole Foods Market", "Safeway", or "Pizzeria Delfina" in the `pickup_name` field. Then I'm to tag the `pickup_name` as a hotspot.

here's the code I've tried:

```
delivery_data = read.csv('Delivery_Data_Problem.csv')

#created vector to hold the text values I'm looking for
hotspot_locations = c("Whole Foods Market", "Safeway", "Pizzeria Delfina")
pickup_sub = list() #init as list

#running through the original data frame to get a list of the hotspots that need tagging
for( i in hotspot_locations){
  pickup_sub[[i]] = delivery_data[delivery_data$pickup_name == i, ]
}
#applies tags to the list pickup_sup
sapply(pickup_sub, function(x){
  if(x$pickup_name == "Whole Foods Market"){
    x$pickup_name = paste(x$pickup_name, '-H1')
  }else if(x$pickup_name == "Safeway"){
    x$pickup_name = paste(x$pickup_name, '-H2')
  }else if(x$pickup_name == "Pizzeria Delfina"){
    x$pickup_name = paste(x$pickup_name, '-H3')
  }
})
#this code works, but isn't exactly what we want with this, we need to tag the original data frame


#this is the first attempt to get just the indexes, but it's not returning just the indexes. should I use which() here?
full_list = delivery_data[(delivery_data$pickup_name == "Whole Foods Market" | delivery_data$pickup_name == 'Safeway' | delivery_data$pickup_name == "Pizzeria Delfina") & delivery_data$pickup_zipcode == 94107,]
# hs_zip is supposed to be a vector of indexes to help an apply function to tag the original data frame. 
hs_zip = delivery_data[which(delivery_data$pickup_zipcode == 94107),]
# then iterate over the rows and attempt to tag.
for(i in delivery_data[hs_zip,]){
  if(i$pickup_name == "Whole Foods Market"){
    i$pickup_name = paste(i$pickup_name, '-H1')
  }else if(i$pickup_name == "Safeway"){
    i$pickup_name = paste(i$pickup_name, '-H2')
  }else if(i$pickup_name == "Pizzeria Delfina"){
    i$pickup_name = paste(i$pickup_name, '-H3')
  }
}
```

the final loop gives the following error. How can I tag the original data frame, and not a copy?

> Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for any looping, simply run `ifelse()`:

```
delivery_data$pickup_name <- ifelse(delivery_data[pickup_zipcode == 94107 &
                                    delivery_data$pickup_name == "Whole Foods Market", 
                                    paste0(delivery_data$pickup_name, "-H1"),
                                    delivery_data$pickup_name)

delivery_data$pickup_name <- ifelse(delivery_data[pickup_zipcode == 94107 &
                                    delivery_data$pickup_name == "Safeway", 
                                    paste0(delivery_data$pickup_name, "-H2"),
                                    delivery_data$pickup_name)

delivery_data$pickup_name <- ifelse(delivery_data[pickup_zipcode == 94107 &
                                    delivery_data$pickup_name == "Pizzeria Delfina", 
                                    paste0(delivery_data$pickup_name, "-H3"),
                                    delivery_data$pickup_name)
```

Alternatively, using nested `ifelse()`:

```
delivery_data$pickup_name <- ifelse(delivery_data$pickup_zipcode == 94107, 
                                    ifelse(delivery_data$pickup_name == "Whole Foods Market", 
                                           paste0(delivery_data$pickup_name, "-H1"), 
                                                  ifelse(delivery_data$pickup_name == "Safeway", 
                                                         paste0(delivery_data$pickup_name, "-H2"),
                                                         ifelse(delivery_data$pickup_name == "Pizzeria Delfina", 
                                                                paste0(delivery_data$pickup_name, "-H3"), 
                                           delivery_data$pickup_name))),
                                    delivery_data$pickup_name)
```

Even less wordy using `with()`:

```
delivery_data$pickup_name <- with(delivery_data, 
                                  ifelse(pickup_zipcode == 94107, 
                                         ifelse(pickup_name == "Whole Foods Market", 
                                                paste0(pickup_name, "-H1"), 
                                                       ifelse(pickup_name == "Safeway", 
                                                              paste0(pickup_name, "-H2"),
                                                                      ifelse(pickup_name == "Pizzeria Delfina", 
                                                                             paste0(pickup_name, "-H3"), 
                                                pickup_name))),
                                         pickup_name))
```